# Wordpress backend caching bug?

Tags: wordpress, caching

When I make an edit to a post in the backend of Wordpress I only see the change when I Control F5 (refresh cache). It happens to all the things I change in the backend of Wordpress (delete plugins, new posts, edit posts, new pages). On the frontend the changes do appear when I refresh normally.

I tried disabling all the plugins but it still does not work. It shows the old content of the posts it only shows the good content when we press CTRL+F5

I hope someone can help me because I really can't find the problem.

Comment: Have you tried it locally or on another host? Sometimes this can be an hosting issue, when there server caching content (one.com for example).